# Why or when do files get owned by daemon?

Tags: filesystem, php, services

I am developing a PHP application that I'm running on an Apache server (using [XAMPP](http://apachefriends.org)). I have a `.public_data` folder that has sub folders enclosing some user data. These sub folders, and the files inside them, get dynamically created by the PHP script.

The owner of `.public_data` and its sub folders is `www-data`. However, strangely, the files inside the sub folders somehow get owned by `daemon` - whereas **all the folders that enclose these files are owned by `www-data`** - and I'm tired of trying solutions from the Internet in vain.

To make things clearer, imagine the file:

```
.public_data/userA1/.details.dat
```

**Owners**:

- **.public_data** *(pre-existing folder)* : www-data
- **userA1** *(created dynamically)*: www-data
- **.details.dat** *(created dynamically)*: daemon

I could change the ownership from `daemon` to `www-data` using the `sudo chmod` command and also via GUI using the `sudo -i nautilus` command but then the PHP script can't delete these files.

Two doubts are driving me crazy:

1. Why can't the PHP script delete the files even after I manually change the file ownerships?
2. My motive is to build a system that can execute all commands at runtime, thus manually changing the ownership of files isn't a solution. I need the files to **inherit** the ownership. **Why do these files get owned by daemon?**

For further clarification, I seek an answer to: **why/when do files get owned by daemon, and how can I prevent it from happening?**

Comment: Who is the user daemon ? What process is this user running ?

Comment: @Panther I'm not sure what you mean by _`Who is the user daemon?`_.

Comment: How can files be owned by daemon ? Who is this mystery user that owns your files?

Comment: @Panther I don't how. When I right click on the files go to Properties > Permissions, it shows `daemon` as the owner. Although, with my little knowledge of Linux, daemon owning files doesn't make sense to me too but it's happening somehow and I don't know why. :-/

Comment: Use the command line. `ls -l`

Comment: @Panther I can see the file owner as `daemon` in the `ls -l` output.

Comment: So you have a user deamon on your system. Who is this user and what process are they running such that they own your files ? `sudo ps aux | grep deamon`. You need to investigate .....

Comment: @Panther As far as I know, `daemon` is **not** a physical user. It's a background process, right? I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: You are confusing two issues. a daemon is a general term to refer to processes running in the background , but you have a user daemon who is creating files or taking ownership of files in some way, no ? We need to know how that is happening in order to fix it, unless you ran `sudo chown daemon:daemon /some/file` by yourself. "Why do these files get owned by daemon?" , because daemon , the user, is running some process or script that is creating or changing ownership of the files.